# angular2 *ngFor setting style on ul>li with a color value passed

Tags: angular

With `*ngFor element <li></li>` is repeating which is fine. `todo.color` property is also passed.

**Question:**

How can I set `li>style` property to add `todo.color` at the end replacing green to display different colors each time coming from object like `style="border-left: 3px solid " + todo.color` . Tried different approaches but ***no success***.

```
 <ul>                           
    <li *ngFor="let todo of _todos" style="border-left: 3px solid green">
        <div>
            <span>{{todo.title}} {{todo.color}}</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `[ngStyle]` directive for more detail check this [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgStyle-directive.html)

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgStyle} from '@angular/common';
@Component({
 selector: 'ngStyle-example',
 template: `
   <h1 [ngStyle]="{'font-style': style, 'font-size': size, 'font-weight': weight}">
     Change style of this text!
   </h1>
   <hr>
   <label>Italic: <input type="checkbox" (change)="changeStyle($event)"></label>
   <label>Bold: <input type="checkbox" (change)="changeWeight($event)"></label>
   <label>Size: <input type="text" [value]="size" (change)="size = $event.target.value"></label>
 `,
 directives: [NgStyle]
})
export class NgStyleExample {
   style = 'normal';
   weight = 'normal';
   size = '20px';
   changeStyle($event: any) {
     this.style = $event.target.checked ? 'italic' : 'normal';
   }
   changeWeight($event: any) {
     this.weight = $event.target.checked ? 'bold' : 'normal';
   }
}
```

Comment: This is better solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <ul>                           
    <li *ngFor="let todo of _todos" style="border-left: 3px solid green" [style.color]="todo.color">
        <div>
            <span>{{todo.title}} {{todo.color}}</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```